# How to randomize a list to meet conditions

Tags: python, list, random

I would like to generate n randomized versions of a list such that with each randomization the ordering is different from the one before and also each element must have a different position than in the list before. I have generated a list of all possible permutations of the list but I am stuck on how to select the sub-lists that match my conditions. I am thinking maybe a list comprehension could work but not sure how to complete it.

```
# constraints: n <= 12

lst = ['John', 'William', 'Michael', 'Victor', 'Tom', 'Charley', 'Patrick', 'David']

permutations = list(itertools.permutations(lst))

randomized_lists = [i for i in permutations if <conditions>]
```

Any ideas how this could be done? Also, is there a better (more efficient) approach to the problem?

Comment: What are your conditions?

Comment: @mario_sunny they said in the question.

Comment: @mario_sunny  **also each element must have a different position**

Comment: `the sub-lists that match my conditions.` - which conditions? Perhaps I am not understanding the question.

Comment: @mario_sunny. OP wants to shuffle a list in such a way that none of the elements end up in their original positions.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by modifying the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) algorithm to avoid swapping one item with itself. That is, for each item at *k* (where *k* starts at 0), instead of choosing a random item in `[0, k]` or `[k, n - 1]` (including `k`), choose a random item in `[0, k)` or `(k, n - 1]` (excluding `k`), and swap the item at *k* with the random item.

---

The following method implements this idea:

```
import random

def shuffle_diff_pos(list):
  """ Returns a shuffled list in which 
      each item moves to a different position. """
  list=[x for x in list]
  if len(list)>=2:
    i=len(list)-1
    while i>0:
      k=random.randint(0, i-1)
      tmp=list[i];list[i]=list[k];list[k]=tmp
      i-=1
  return list

lst = ['John', 'William', 'Michael', 'Victor', 'Tom', 'Charley', 'Patrick', 'David']
randomized_lists = [shuffle_diff_pos(lst) for _ in range(12)]
```

Comment: I've been working on an answer with the same content and an implementation. I don't think the result will be 100% uniform, can't come up with a satisfactory explanation or fix. +1

Comment: @Peter This seems like an interesting answer. Could you put a sample code?

Comment: I am not sure that your code covers the three possibilities when it comes to swapping the elements. I have posted an answer that basically elaborates on your initial idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this list comprehension:

```
result = [i for i in permutations if any(a != b for a, b in zip(i, lst))]
```

We are `any(a == b for a, b in zip(i, lst)` testing if any matching item on same index in `lst` and permutaion in this line.

Comment: `any(a == b in zip(item, lst))`?

Comment: You can make `result` a generator so you don't have to build the whole thing at once.

Comment: Please, feel free to edit my answer. I did not quite actually understand because what a and b means.

Comment: `a` and `b` are a brain fart. I meant `any(a == b for a, b in zip(item, lst))`. I'd prefer not to touch your code.

Comment: Oh okey, now i understood thanks :) I will edit my answer.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop at all. With this condition, you can use a list comprehension.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `if all(a != b ...`

Answer (score 0):

Only your second condition is necessary: if all the elements are not in their original position, the order will be different. Rather than looking through all possible permutations and choosing one randomly, (which is even more inefficient than shuffling until your condition is met), you can generate a list to your spec.

Your list has 8 elements, which means that each position can have one of 7 options (all but the element currently there). This is equivalent to placing ones in a matrix of zeros such that no one occupies the same row or column as another (normal shuffling), but with the restriction that elements can not be on the main diagonal, which complicates things.

You can implement a [Fisher-Yates-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle which includes the restrictions. This will randomize your list without having to sift through vast numbers of permutations.

It's probably easier to work with indices to avoid placement collisions, rather than looking up the position of each element as it's swapped.

```
n = len(lst)
ind = list(range(n))
for i in range(n - 1):
    # Case 1: Swap out necessary, conflictonly with self
    if ind[i] == i:
        swap_ind = random.randrange(i + 1, n)
    else:
        try:
            # Case 2: swap might cause conflict
            ind_of_i = ind.index(i, i + 1)
            swap_ind = random.randrange(i, n - 1)
            if swap_ind >= ind_of_i:
                swap_ind += 1
        except ValueError:
            # Case 3: no conflict, full range available
            swap_ind = random.randrange(i, n)
    ind[i], ind[swap_ind] = ind[swap_ind], ind[i]
```

You now have a list of shuffled indices, none of which has ended up in the same spot it started in. You can arrange the input list with

```
result = [lst[i] for i in ind]
```

Keep in mind that the implementation of the check `ind[swap_ind]` is very inefficient in time, and effectively negates the benefit of sorting indices instead of the actual values. You can replace it with a second list that maintains an inverse lookup table of index to position, and swap that along with `ind`. The result will be `O(1)` lookup and twice as much memory utilization.

I am not sure how uniform the result will be over the space of all available permutations, but I suspect that (a) it is probably good enough for what you are looking for, and (b) can be easily modified to be more uniform if necessary/possible.

Comment: I re-worded the question and got a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773283/reordering-a-list-to-meet-conditions

Comment: @Clifton. The reword is functionally identical to this question. The answer to the other question suggests random shuffling and weeding out the non-conforming elements. The probability of getting stuck in that methods is negligibly low, but it's still not efficient. You should select one of the answers you have here.