# Reordering a list to meet conditions

Tags: python, list, sorting, optimization, permutation

For a certain course at a university, students are expected to present on topics each week for class. The students present in a random order each week.

The function  `presOrder` is supposed to receive two parameters, (1) a positive integer n representing a number of weeks of presentations, and (2) a list of names in the order that must be maintained only for the first presentation. The function returns a list of  lists for the presentation order for the  weeks; each of the  lists contains the given names in a completely randomized order ensuring that the names are in a different order from that of the previous week and each name in a different position from that of the previous week. A different order means that the names before and after in the previous week should not be the same in the week following.

```
import random
import itertools

def notRandom(lst, plst, no):
    result = True
    for i in range(no-1):
        result = result and (lst[i] == plst[i+1])
    result = result and (lst[no-1] == plst[0])
    if result:
        return True
    result = True
    for i in range(1,no):
        result = result and (lst[i] == plst[i-1])
    result = result and (lst[0] == plst[no-1])
    if result:
        return True
    return False


# My attempt
def presOrder(n, namelst):
    permutation = itertools.permutations(namelst)
    rand = [] + [namelst]
    prev = namelst
    for lst in permutation:
        if not(notRandom(lst, prev, len(namelst))) and len(rand) < n:
            rndom = True
            for i in range(len(namelst)):
                if not(lst[i] == prev[i]):
                    rndom = rndom and True
                else:
                    rndom = rndom and False
            if rndom:
                rand += [lst]
                prev = lst[:]
        else:
            continue
    return rand


names = ['Abi Jones', 'Bob King', 'Carl Llewellyn', 'Danielle McIntosh', 'Earl Newell', 'Frank Olephante', 'George Brown', 'Harry Zephers']

#example
>>> print(presOrder(5, names))
>>> [['Abi Jones', 'Bob King', 'Carl Llewellyn', 'Danielle McIntosh', 'Earl Newell', 'Frank Olephante', 'George Brown', 'Harry Zephers'], ('Bob King', 'Abi Jones', 'Danielle McIntosh', 'Carl Llewellyn', 'Frank Olephante', 'Earl Newell', 'Harry Zephers', 'George Brown'), ('Carl Llewellyn', 'Bob King', 'Abi Jones', 'Danielle McIntosh', 'Earl Newell', 'Frank Olephante', 'George Brown', 'Harry Zephers'), ('Danielle McIntosh', 'Abi Jones', 'Bob King', 'Carl Llewellyn', 'Frank Olephante', 'Earl Newell', 'Harry Zephers', 'George Brown'), ('Earl Newell', 'Bob King', 'Abi Jones', 'Danielle McIntosh', 'Carl Llewellyn', 'Frank Olephante', 'George Brown', 'Harry Zephers')]
```

The code seems to work (somewhat) as it is, but I'll need to test it more. In the meantime, how can I optimize the code for `presOrder`?

Comment: To be honest - your code is a little too long for me to understand its idea at the moment. However, the problem is interesting and I'd like to know if the large equality of week n and n+2 is on purpose or a drawback which should still be optimized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomize a list to meet conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717491/how-to-randomize-a-list-to-meet-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be like this:

```
import random

def test_positions(L1, L2):
    return any(a==b for a, b in zip(L1, L2))

def neighbours(L):
    return [set([a, b]) for a, b in zip(L[:-1], L[1:])]

def test_neighbours(L1, L2):
    return any(nb in neighbours(L2) for nb in neighbours(L1))

def pres_order(n, L):
    result = [names[:]]
#   random.shuffle(result[0])    # only needed for reording first row
    for i in range(1, n):
        result.append(names[:])
        random.shuffle(result[-1])
        while test_positions(result[-1], result[-2]) or test_neighbours(result[-1], result[-2]):
            random.shuffle(result[-1])
    return result
```

The idea is to first create a *(randomly reordered (shuffled))* version of the names list.
Then append a next shuffled version - but shuffle again and again until your two requirements are met.
Append until length of list == n.

The two requirements are implemented in the `test_...` functions.
The first one about positions is self explaining I think.
The second one checks if any neighbours of the last row appear also as neighbours in the last but one row.
To achieve this, there is a helper function to create the lists of neighbour pairs.

Note that the `set` function in the neighbour definition will prevent neighboured name pairs in adjacent rows independant of their order. If you want to prevent only the exact copy of a pair (e.g. after `[...'E', 'G',... ]` `[...'G', 'E',... ]` should be allowed but `[...'E', 'G',... ]` not), you can simply leave the set function away.

---

Example:

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
for l in pres_order(5, names):
    print(l)

# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
# ['G', 'B', 'H', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'A', 'D']
# ['H', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G']
# ['C', 'F', 'E', 'H', 'A', 'G', 'B', 'D']
# ['G', 'H', 'B', 'F', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'C']
```

---

Edit:
I just realized that the first row should be the unaltered original list. Therefore I commented the first shuffle out; so you can easily get it back if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for this. Remember though that the first list in the output should always be the original input list and then the randomized versions should follow according to the conditions.